# Multiple shared datasets in different report projects

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bids

I have a database called CommonDB. I have created shared data sets from this database in one of my report projects. I now have a need to include the same shared data sets in another report project. Ideally it would be nice if I could just point it to the testing site in BIDS and develop my report based on a reference.

I was wondering if there is a way to do this without adding existing data set (as I was hoping to keep the code base the same so I wouldn't have to update it in different projects).I am aware you can also add existing data sets from url but that defeats the purpose as it just downloads a copy to my report solution and it's not synced.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is not supported by BIDS/Visual Studio.

It gets worse: If you deploy multiple projects to the same server, using the same Shared Datasets folder, then at runtime they will try to reuse each-others Shared Dataset definitions.  The latest deployed Shared Dataset definition will win.

Data Sources have similar issues - although they tend to be less volatile.

To avoid this, I prefer to keep all reports for a single SSRS server instance in a single BIDS/Visual Studio Project.  I use Project Configurations to manage deployment of reports to disparate folders.